# Can't delete an app? (iTunesConnect)

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect

I have the admin and legal role for my app(I am the sole developer). I want to delete it because it got rejected but there is no delete button. Any help?

Comment: It belongs to Apple now, they'll re-brand it and sell it back to you for an extortionate amount of money! ;)

Comment: lol no it was rejected and i want to delete it

Comment: hehe. @The Blue Dog was just kidding. But the fact is you can't delete a rejected app from iTunesConnect since one or two months ago. There's no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete it if it falls into one of the listing statuses found in the docs  [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW37).

If you're still unable to see these options, there's some other issue and I'd recommend calling or emailing.